# Apple Watch unlock feature for macOS Sierra requires turning off 2-step-verification

Tags: security, apple-id, apple-watch, macos

Yesterday I installed macOS Sierra and now I want to enable this new feature - unlocking MacBook with Apple Watch.

I opened `Security & Privacy` settings and tried to check this option (`Allow your Apple Watch to unlock your Mac`). It asked me for my **iCloud** (**Apple ID**) password, I provided it, but then it showed me the following message:

[image]

Some additional info (if it's relevant):

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- macOS Sierra 10.12
- Bluetooth LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)

And yes, I have two-step verification enabled in my **Apple ID** for about a year now:

[image]

So, to have this feature enabled I need to reduce protection of the entire **Apple ID**? Can I bypass this requirement and use the watch to unlock my Mac?

Comment: I'm going to edit the why and focus on the existence of any workarounds. Someone will clearly answer your post with - "No - there isn't a workaround" so be open to that possibility.

Comment: Make sure you review [this recent article](http://www.macrumors.com/how-to/macos-sierra-apple-watch-unlock/) on how to unlock your Mac with your Watch.  It might answer your questions.

Comment: Great question, by the way - I sure hope I'm wrong and there are options. Even if it's a deep dive into how this works and it's fragile or hacky - I'd love to learn more about how we can customize Apple's hardware even if their software wants you to follow the pack with their mainstream options.

Comment: I think you need to disable 'two-step verification' and use 'two-factor authentication', instead.

Comment: @fbara you are right. I did not know, that Apple introduced two-FACTOR authentication after having two-STEP verification. I switched to it and everything's fine now. You can write this as an answer.

Comment: ...and restored initial wording in my question, because the entire point was missing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to **disable** *two-step verification* and **enable** *two-factor authentication*.

If you follow the steps in [this article](http://www.macrumors.com/how-to/macos-sierra-apple-watch-unlock/), it will show you how you can use your Watch to wake-up your Mac.  One of the key parts is at the bottom of the article:

> For those of you using the original **Two-Step Verification** instead of the **Two-Factor Authentication** feature introduced with iOS 10, you will need to disable Two-Step Verification on the Apple ID management site and then enable Two-Factor Authentication on an iOS device. A passcode also needs to be established on the Apple Watch.

Comment: What's the difference between Two-Step Verification and Two-Factor Verification?

Answer (score 1):

No - Apple's code to perform the unlock explicitly doesn't support two factor. I was willing to change my security, but understand your concerns.

The workaround would be to use a third party unlock service like https://www.macid.co and use their software to unlock your computer.

Sadly, I don't think their implementation is as efficient, reliable or secure as Apple's so I'm making the change Apple asked. My speculation is two-step will be shut off within a year and that two-factor will become more secure than it is today. Those are guesses and opinion, though.