# Apple Watch won't unlock MacBook Pro unless watch is restarted

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, apple-watch

My issue is unlocking my Mac with the Apple Watch feature.
I've read where turning off the watch and phone will then in turn allow me to unlock my Mac.  This works, the problem is, I have to do this every single day.  Since enabling this feature, I haven't gone two days in a row without having to restart my watch/phone to be able to use this feature.  Once I do this, the feature works great all day.  But it's very frustrating to have to do this on a daily basis.

Note: I turn my Mac off at night and turn in on in the morning at work.
Anyone else having this same problem, or know of a fix?

Apple Watch OS: 3.1(14S471) 1st Gen watch
iPhone OS: 10.2(14C92) iPhone 5s
Macbook Pro OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.1 15-inch late 2013

Comment: Have you setup the two-step verification correctly?  See [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/253799/88313) for info.

Comment: I have Two-Factor Authentication turned on, like I said, I log in to my computer in the morning with my password, but when I lock it to go grab a snack or something, if I want to use my watch to unlock my mac, I then have to restart both watch and phone, then it works perfectly fine the rest of the day.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the question about the two-factor authentication so I wasn't sure.  There's many questions here about using the Watch to unlock the Mac and most of them are because it wasn't setup correctly to start, so I wanted to eliminate that as part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in macOS 10.12.2.
From Apples release notes:
Improves setup and reliability of Auto Unlock.
Today was the first day I haven't had to restart my phone and watch!

Comment: I'm hoping it will no longer be slower than typing my password or using Knock.  Because up until now both of those are MUCH faster options

Comment: I'm just hoping I type an answer too soon.  It better continue working tomorrow also!!

Comment: *didn't type an ...